# Casting scientific string to float in pyspark 2.4 gives rounding error

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe in which I want to add a numeric value to another numeric value. When the original numeric value is formatted as double from an scientific notated string it works, when it is formatted as float it gives a rounding error.

```
def updateValue(value):
   return (value + 10)

updateValueUdf_double = udf(updateValue, DoubleType())
updateValueUdf_float = udf(updateValue, FloatType())

// create simple dataframe
data = [(0, "1E8")]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ["row", "value"])

df2 = df.withColumn("value_d", col("value").cast("double"))\
.withColumn("value_du", updateValueUdf_double("value_d"))\
.withColumn("value_f", col("value").cast("float"))\
.withColumn("value_fu", updateValueUdf_float("value_f"))

df2.show(n=2)
```

When I run the above code it gives me the correct value for value_du, but incorrect for value_fu, see below. Is this expected behavior and should I always use DoubleType?

```
+---+-----+-------+-----------+-------+------------+
|row|value|value_d|   value_du|value_f|    value_fu|
+---+-----+-------+-----------+-------+------------+
|  0|  1E8|  1.0E8|1.0000001E8|  1.0E8|1.00000008E8|
+---+-----+-------+-----------+-------+------------+
```